# Native speech recognition software for Linux

Tags: software-rec, speech-recognition

I am looking for a user friendly speech-to-text software to run offline on linux.

Simon needs a dictionary and training, I need a full dictation-able software, speechpad needs internet access, julius and sphinx are engines not for end-user. I am in doubt if there is a solution.

Look, I am able to install softwares via ssh tunneling connection, but it is a pain in the neck to hold this connection forever, I am not allowed to give internet access to this machine, I would rather not to, just for installing purposes, after that it should run natively and offline.

For now it is Ubuntu 16.04.1. Is there any solution?

Comment: Does it need to be free? AFAIK this is a domain where you still get a lot better results with expensive software.

Comment: @Gilles, I would glad if it was, it is a pitty, we have a new coworker wich is deaf, and we have a PC on a TV as dashboard, we were planning to install some software on this machine to facilitate communication during the daily meeting. I thought linux community were working on disabled inclusion, but I was mistaken.